# ngbDatepicker : Differentiate between invalid date format and out of range(minDate/maxDate) value for user feedback

Tags: html, angular, validation, jhipster, ng-bootstrap

I have a jHipster app, and this is the birth date input field :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label" for="field_birthDate">Birth Date</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="field_birthDate" type="text" class="form-control" name="birthDate" ngbDatepicker  #birthDateDp="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="registerAccount.birthDate"
        required #birthDate="ngModel" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" [minDate]="birthDateValidation.minDate" [maxDate]="birthDateValidation.maxDate" pattern="(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))"/>
        <span class="input-group-append">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="birthDateDp.toggle()"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="birthDate.dirty && birthDate.invalid">
        <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="birthDate.errors.required">
            Your birth date is required.
        </small>
        <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="birthDate.errors.pattern">
            Your birth date must be a valid date (Ex: yyyy-mm-dd).
        </small>
        <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="!birthDate.errors.required && !birthDate.errors.pattern">
            Your age must be between 18 and 100.
        </small>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem with this solution is when i add a "pattern" to the input field no matter what value i enter, it's always considered as invalid. (most likely because the "pattern" attribute is incompatible with the "ngbDatepicker" attribute)

My question : is there an alternative where i can differentiate between a value with an invalid format (other than 'yyyy-mm-dd') and a value out of range specified in minDate/maxDate for better user feedback ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are looking for an answer, the validation is already implemented by the directive [NgbInputDatepicker](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker-input.ts), so here's the solution :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label" for="field_birthDate">Birth Date</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="field_birthDate" type="text" class="form-control" name="birthDate" ngbDatepicker #birthDateDp="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="registerAccount.birthDate" [minDate]="ngbDatepickerConfig.minDate" [maxDate]="ngbDatepickerConfig.maxDate" required #birthDate="ngModel" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"/>
        <span class="input-group-append">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="birthDateDp.toggle()"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="birthDate.dirty && birthDate.invalid">
        <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="birthDate.errors.required">
            Your birth date is required.
        </small>
        <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="birthDate.errors.ngbDate?.invalid">
            Your birth date must be a valid date (Ex: yyyy-mm-dd).
        </small>
        <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="birthDate.errors.ngbDate?.requiredBefore || birthDate.errors.ngbDate?.requiredAfter">
            Your age must be between 18 and 100.
        </small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a bit more updated version that is no longer using `ngModel`, you can do something like this to use ngbDatepicker's validation. If someone decides to try to type in a date and they mess it up, this will catch it.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.employeeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    HireDate: ['', Validators.required],
  });
}

get form() {
  return this.employeeForm.controls;
}

<label for="HireDate">Hire Date *</label>
<input
    id="HireDate"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName="HireDate"
    type="text"
    placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"
    (focus)="HireDatePicker.toggle()"
    #HireDatePicker="ngbDatepicker"
    ngbDatepicker
    required
>
<div *ngIf="submitted && form.HireDate.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="form.HireDate.errors.required">Hire date is required</div>
    <div *ngIf="form.HireDate.errors.ngbDate.invalid">Hire date must be YYYY-MM-DD</div>
</div>
```